# Colorblind-friendly dark theme for Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, rstudio, accessibility, color-blindness

New to Eclipse.  The out-of-box dark theme isn't adequate for colorblind folks.  I've circled the words I can't read due to colorblindness.  How can I get something like the Cobalt theme that is available in RStudio?

Eclipse:

[Words I can't see due to colorblindness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kif7S.png)

RStudio:

[Excellent example of colorblind-friendly theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5snz.png)

Comment: Hi  @floattheboat - welcome to SO - you should maybe remove the #rstudio tag on hat one since this is NOT an RStudio related question, just a reference to how an Eclipse solution could look like.

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is probably too late for you, but I got to your question while searching myself.

For people in the future with the same problem:

I have a red/green deficiency and I installed the "Eclipse Color Theme" Addon from the Marketplace.

By then you have a reasonably large selection in the preferences. (General -> Appearance -> Color Theme).

Anyway...
I wasnt happy with it so I imported the [ColorBlind](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=8801) theme.